# Get deployment manifest from Iothub configuration using .net

Tags: c#, .net, azure, api, azure-iot-hub

**What I want:**

I want to duplicate, change and deploy a configuration in iothub using .net, however I cannot figure out how to get the deployment manifest (`deployment_manifest.json`) using the API.

I want the deployment manifest from my selected configuration as an object.

**What I tried:**

```
private static string GetConfiguration(string iotHubName, string token)
        {
            using var client = new HttpClient();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", token);

            var restUriGet = $"https://{iotHubName}/api/deploymentManifests/opcpublisher?api-version=2022-10-31-preview";

            using var resultGet = client.GetAsync(restUriGet).Result;
            return resultGet.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
```

This gives me a bad request error

---

```
private static string GetConfiguration(string iotHubName, string token)
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", token);

        var restUriGet = $"https://{iotHubName}/configurations/opcpublisher?api-version=2020-05-31-preview";

        using var resultGet = client.GetAsync(restUriGet).Result;
        return resultGet.StatusCode.ToString();
    }
```

This gives me a lot of information but no JSON.

Here is the documentation/tutorial I used: ***[microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/configuration)** / **[tutorial](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2020/07/16/deploy-azure-iot-edge-deployment-manifest-programmatically/)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The bad request error could be due to an incorrect `manifestId` or `token`.

Check whether you are passing the correct values of `manifestId` or `token`. And also check that you have the correct permissions to access the deployment manifest.

```
string con = "Connection String";
string device_Id = "deviceId";
string str = GenSas_Token(con, device_Id);

 

var iotHub = "IotHub";
var deployment_ManifestId = "ManifestId";
var token = str;

 

var clnt = new HttpClient();
clnt.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", token);
var restUriGet = $"https://{iotHub}.azureiotcentral.com/api/deploymentManifests/{deployment_ManifestId}?api-version=2022-10-31-preview";

 

var resultGet = await clnt.GetAsync(restUriGet);
var content = await resultGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

 

//To fetch Token
public static string GenSas_Token(string HubConn, string deviceId)
        {
            var builder = new SharedAccessSignatureBuilder()
            {
                Key = "Key",
                Target = $"{HubConn}/devices/{deviceId}",
                TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)
            };

 

            return builder.ToSignature();
        }
```

[image]

Thanks @ **Sander van de Velde** for the [Blog](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2020/07/16/deploy-azure-iot-edge-deployment-manifest-programmatically/).

For further information, refer to the [MSDoc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-manage-deployment-manifests-with-rest-api)